# InfluxDB Correct DateTime in Graph but not in Raw Data

Tags: influxdb, utc

I'm new to InfluxDB and have a strange issue. Couldn't find any solution to this :-(
I'm sending data to InfluxDB and the date/time shows correctly in the graph. But when I select "View Raw Data" the Data is shown in UTC time, 2 hours back.
How can I solve this?
As additional information: I have setup Container Station on QNAP and made a Docker Container with InfluxDB. I had already there an issue that the Container had UTC time and I could solve it with the following mounts:
-v /etc/TZ:/etc/timezone 
-v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime 
That fixed the problem. QNAP Host and Container have booth the same time.
Would appreciate any help on this.
Thanks and cheers
Markus

Searched on Google with no success